# Adding seconds to HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript

I've seen posts around converting seconds into a `HH:MM:SS` format but I have a string variable which is in that format `(HH:MM:SS)` and I have another variable which returns a number. I'm trying to treat that number as seconds and then add the seconds to the `HH:MM:SS` format.

Example:

If the first variable is `12:03:57` and the second variable is `6`
then the third variable should evaluate to `12:04:03`

I'd prefer to do this without having to use anything external.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: welcome to stack overflow plz check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The basic method when calculating times is to change the time to ten-based number at first, then do the math, and finally convert back to time. Now that you've a time as a string should not be any problem, JS is full of converters.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by a ten-based number? HH:MM:SS comes to 6 - what populates the remaining 4?

Comment: _“Can you elaborate on what you mean by a ten-based number? HH:MM:SS comes to 6”_ - not, that is absolutely not what was meant by “base”. They meant the _decimal system_, as opposed to the system used by numbers and minutes, which uses “base 60”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your string time to a Date object, which you can then turn into milliseconds. From there, you can offset your time by `6` seconds (ie: `6000` milliseconds) to get your new date time. You can then extract each date component (hours, minutes, seconds), and `.map()` it such that it has a `0` padding for each single digit. Lastly, you can join each element in your array with `':'` to match the time format:

```js
const start = "12:03:57";
const offset = 6;
const date = new Date(+new Date(`1970-01-01T${start}Z`) + offset*1000);
const formattedStr = [date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes() , date.getUTCSeconds()].map(n => n.toString().padStart(2, 0)).join(':');
console.log(formattedStr);
```